# jQuery ajax in ie7

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I really hope someone can help me with this. Basically i have an issue with an ajax-call in jQuery in ie7. The script work in every other browser than ie7.

The ajax always return error in ie7.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

//Run Ajax on Click
$('#GlsSubmit').click(function(){

//Get input from textfields
street = $("#GlsStreet").val(); 
zip = $("#GlsZip").val();

//How many results to show
amount = '5';
var time = new Date;

//Initiate Ajax (fetch xml-data from .asp in applications folder)
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.test.dk/gls.aspx?street="+street+"&zip="+zip+"&amount="+amount+"&dummy="+ time.getTime(),
    success: function(msg){

        //Saving Shop data
        CompanyName = $(msg).find("PakkeshopData").html();
        $('#GlsResults').html('');
        $(msg).find("PakkeshopData").each(function(index){

            CompanyName = $(this).find('CompanyName').text();
            CompanyStreetName = $(this).find('StreetName').text();
            CompanyZipCode = $(this).find('ZipCode').text();
            CompanyCityName = $(this).find('CityName').text();
            CompanyID = $(this).find('Number').text();
            $('#GlsResults').append("<input type='radio' class='required' name='shopSelecter' id='shopSelecter"+index+"' value='"+CompanyID+"'/><label for='shopSelecter"+index+"'>"+ CompanyName +", "+CompanyStreetName+", " + CompanyZipCode + " "+ CompanyCityName +"</label><div class='clear'></div>");

        }); //End of each

        //See if user choses another shop
        $('#GlsResults input[type=radio]').change(function(){
            shopid = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.test.dk/gls2.aspx?ParcelShopNumber="+shopid,
                success: function(data){

                        //Save oinfo for the chosen shop
                        CompanyNameSingle = $(data).find('CompanyName').text();
                        CompanyStreetNameSingle = $(data).find('StreetName').text();
                        CompanyZipCodeSingle = $(data).find('ZipCode').text();
                        CompanyCityNameSingle = $(data).find('CityName').text();
                        CompanyIDSingle = $(data).find('StreetName2').text();

                        //Change values for input fields
                        $('#EcomOrderDeliveryAddress2').val(CompanyIDSingle);
                        $('#EcomOrderDeliveryName').val(CompanyNameSingle);
                        $('#EcomOrderDeliveryAddress').val(CompanyStreetNameSingle);
                        $('#EcomOrderDeliveryZip').val(CompanyZipCodeSingle);
                        $('#EcomOrderDeliveryCity').val(CompanyCityNameSingle);

                }, //End of succes

                error:function(response){

                } //End of error

            }); // End of ajax

        }); // End of radio button change

        $("#gls-error").hide();

   }, //End of succes
     error:function(response){
     //Error Messages
     if( zip == ''){
        $("#GlsResults").html("<div id='gls-error'>Indtast venligst et postnummer</div>");
     }

     else if( !(zip.length == 4)){
        $("#GlsResults").html("<div id='gls-error'>Indtast venligst et postnummer på 4 cifre</div>");
     }

     else{
        $("#GlsResults").html("<div id='gls-error'>Kunne ikke finde et pakkecenter</div>");
        }
    } //End of error
  }); // End of ajax
  }); //End of click



}); //End of document.ready


</script>
```

Anyone got any ideas :-)?

Thanks!

Comment: which error ? do you mean the first error callback or the second? or something else ?

Comment: cross domain requests are not supported in IE7

Comment: What is the error in IE7

Comment: also I'm surprised by `var time = new Date`; is it equivalent to `var time = new Date();` ?

Comment: @BiAiB: I'm sorry to say it is, yes. It's even covered by the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone got any ideas

Yes: *Break that up into smaller pieces.* That kind of deep nesting is very hard to read, maintain, and troubleshoot. :-)

Without your having said *what* error, here are some other observations which may help you get going on it:

1. If the page that this script is running in isn't on `http://www.fricykler.dk`, that's your problem. You're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
2. If it *is* on `http://www.fricykler.dk`, remove that from the `ajax` calls (just use `url: '/gls.aspx...'`).
3. Unless you're declaring `street`, `zip`, and others in code you haven't quoted, you're falling prey to the [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Recommend declaring them. Who knows, maybe you're overwriting something important, since the `window` namespace gets *very* cluttered on IE.
4. Walk through the code, step-by-step, in a debugger. You can use [the free edition of Visual Studio.Net](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) to debug client-side code in IE7. (In general, here in 2011 there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) not to use a debugger for your client-side work.)

Other observations that almost certainly are *not* the problem:

- *Every time* you call `$()`, it has to do several function calls, a memory allocation, and if you're passing it a selector (even an ID selector), it has to do a DOM query. So whenever you find yourself repeating it (`CompanyName = $(this).find('CompanyName').text();`, `CompanyStreetName = $(this).find('StreetName').text();`, ...). Consider doing it once and remembering the result (`var $this = $(this);` then `CompanyName = $this.find('CompanyName').text();`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for some very constructive input! I'll try too take a look at it :-)